# How can meta boxes be added to "unknown" custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I'm running WP multi-site and I've created a plugin that adds meta boxes to my page and post.

```
add_meta_box( 'Intro', __('Intro'), 'sewp_post_intro_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
add_meta_box( 'Intro', __('Intro'), 'sewp_post_intro_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
```

The problem is that this isn't added for my custom post types. Adding another `add_meta_box` in my plugin isn't an option since it will only be relevant for this customer.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "unknown custom posts", but here is how you'd add a meta box to a number of post types:

```
$post_types = array(
    'post',
    'page',
    'my_custom_post_type',
);
foreach ($post_types as $post_type)
    add_meta_box('Intro', __('Intro'), 'my_meta_box', $post_type, 'normal', 'high');
```

If you would like to have different contexts and/or priorities, you have to do it in multiple calls.

If I misunderstood you, please enlighten me.

**// Edit**
Of course, you could do it *the other way around*, and exclude post types that you do **not** want to have this meta box.

```
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
);
if (! is_array($post_types = get_post_types($args)))
    $post_types = array();

unset($post_types['post']);
unset($post_types['attachment']);
unset($post_types['my_custom_post_type']);

if (count($post_types))
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type)
        add_meta_box('Intro', __('Intro'), 'my_meta_box', $post_type, 'normal', 'high');
```

If this isn't what you're looking for either, I'm afraid I have no idea what you would be satisfied with.

You don't want to specify post types, but want some functionality bound to specific post types...

Comment: This is exactly the solution I'm trying to avoid because I'm using this plugin on all my sites. Some single sites and some multi-sites. Having a bunch of extra post types in the array doesn't make sense for the other sites. So I'm hoping there is a way do add them to "any post types"

Comment: @Steven what's the difference between "any post types" and "all post types"? Are you just picking a random post type to add this to?

Comment: @Steven Please see my edit to the above answer.

Comment: @Steven Could you explain why you want to avoid adding metaboxes to custom post types, when in your question you said that the problem was your metaboxes weren't being added to custom post types? I think we're confused what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @t-f. The best way would be if there was a way to "tell" my plugin to add custom meta boxes to this new post type (from my theme's functions.php). But I guess I just have to use your first solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `NULL` or an *empty string* as the `$screen` input value:

```
add_meta_box( 'Intro', 
               __('Intro'), 
              'sewp_post_intro_meta_box', 
              $screen = '', 
              'normal', 
              'high' 
            );
```

to add the meta box to *any "screenable"* post type, because then the [default](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L800) is:

```
 if ( empty( $screen ) )
     $screen = get_current_screen();
```

*ps:* If you need some specific post types or better control, you should use what @t f suggested.